# How to Decrease the First Byte Time?

Tags: wordpress, performance, pagespeed, webpagetest

Straight to the question I've searched the answer in stackoverflow and I'm not convinced with the answers listed here.

Link to my website : http://www.bestowe.com

Webpagetest.org result :All values are good except first byte time

GTmetrix Result : https://gtmetrix.com/reports/bestowe.com/D9I61AYK ( both the Yslow and page speed is above 90%)

Google page speed test : both for the mobile and desktop is around 70%

And my site is a wordpress website and it's hosted in shared VPS but I've changed the DNS to cloudflare free service which improved my site performance drastically and my concern is

1. How to reduce the first byte time?
2. How to increase the performance in google page speed?

Regards,
John

Answer (score 1):

Time To First Byte is the amount of time the server takes to start returning data. You are right in thinking it has a major SEO affect.

This is usually a consequence of server-side dynamic code being slow to render; in your case the PHP scripts are taking too long to run on the server. In order to fix this you usually need either more server power or better code. Here are your options:

1. Get a better, more optimised server. Move hosts if necessary; there are plenty of good, low cost ones.
2. I notice you're using WordPress. Consider installing a server side caching plugin, such as [W3 Total Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/).
3. Optimise your site by reducing the amount of WordPress plugins.
4. If you manage your own server, optimise your configuration ([here's a guide for Apache](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-optimize-apache-web-server-performance)). Well, in your case you're using Varnish and you aren't getting that much load as it is so there's probably no major changes if you do. Just check your PHP memory limits are right.